# zend framework 2 captcha helper view render inline

Tags: captcha, zend-framework2, view-helpers

I am try render the captcha element using formCaptcha Helper View how follows:

```
    $this->formElementErrors()
        ->setMessageOpenFormat('<br><span class="error-message">')
        ->setMessageCloseString('</span>');
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form); 
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('mail')) . "<br>";
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('password')) . "<br>";
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('name')) . "<br>";
    echo $this->formCaptcha($form->get('captcha')) . "<br>";
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('register-button')); 
    echo $this->formRow($form->get('register-type'));
    echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

But the captcha render all HTML tags with inline mode how show the image:

[image]

How I can see the images as a block, (i.e.: the text field bellow the image)?

Answer (score 3):

There is no short answer to your question that I am aware of.
I had a similar need and built a solution and have a blog post plus github code available.
[http://zendtemple.blogspot.com/2012/12/zend-framework-2-zf2-creating-view.html][1]

I created my own view helper and register it with the invokables in the PhpRenderer.

I then created a new custom captcha image class that extends the original zend captcha image class and overrides the 'getHelperName' function to point at the new helper.

The default Zend\Form\View\Helper\Captcha\Image.php render function employs a pattern for the captcha image, the input box, and the id. It looks like this:

```
$pattern = '%s%s%s';
if ($position == self::CAPTCHA_PREPEND) {
    return sprintf($pattern, $captchaInput, $separator, $img);
}
return sprintf($pattern, $img, $separator, $captchaInput);
```

In you custom view helper you can create any pattern you'd like.

Here is my custom view helper. I rewrote the pattern and wrapped the elements in separate divs:
//module\Application\src\Application\View\Helper\Form\Custom\Captcha\ViewHelperCaptcha.php

```
namespace  Application\View\Helper\Form\Custom\Captcha;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\Captcha\AbstractWord;
//our custom captcha image extending the orginal
use Application\View\Helper\Form\Custom\Captcha\CustomCaptcha as CaptchaAdapter;
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
use Zend\Form\Exception;

class ViewHelperCaptcha extends AbstractWord
{
 /**
 * Override
  * 
  * Render the captcha
  *
  * @param  ElementInterface $element
  * @throws Exception\DomainException
  * @return string
  */
 public function render(ElementInterface $element)
 {
 //we could also set the separator here to break between the inputs and the image.
 //$this->setSeparator('
')
  $captcha = $element->getCaptcha();

if ($captcha === null || !$captcha instanceof CaptchaAdapter) {
   throw new Exception\DomainException(sprintf(
     '%s requires that the element has a "captcha" attribute of type     Zend\Captcha\Image; none found',
     __METHOD__
   ));
  }

  $captcha->generate();

  $imgAttributes = array(
    'width'  => $captcha->getWidth(),
    'height' => $captcha->getHeight(),
    'alt'    => $captcha->getImgAlt(),
    'src'    => $captcha->getImgUrl() . $captcha->getId() . $captcha->getSuffix(),
  );
  $closingBracket = $this->getInlineClosingBracket();
  $img = sprintf(
    '<img %s%s',
    $this->createAttributesString($imgAttributes),
    $closingBracket
  );

  $position     = $this->getCaptchaPosition();
  $separator    = $this->getSeparator();
  $captchaInput = $this->renderCaptchaInputs($element);

  $pattern = '<div class="captcha_image">%s</div>%s<div class="captcha_input">%s</div>'
  if ($position == self::CAPTCHA_PREPEND) {
   return sprintf($pattern, $captchaInput, $separator, $img);
  }

  return sprintf($pattern, $img, $separator, $captchaInput);
 }

}
```

Now I need to register this helper in the invokables:

```
\modules\Application\config\module.config.php
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
    'viewhelpercaptcha' =>'Application\View\Helper\Form\Custom\Captcha\ViewHelperCaptcha',
    ),
),
```

Here is my CustomCaptcha extending the original and orverriding the 'getHelperName' to point at my newly registered view helper 'viewhelpercaptcha':
\module\Application\src\Application\View\Helper\Form\Custom\Captcha\CustomCaptcha.php

```
namespace  Application\View\Helper\Form\Custom\Captcha;

//The orginial that we are intending to extend from
use Zend\Captcha\Image as CaptchaImage;
//The new extend verision were we override only what we need.
class CustomCaptcha extends CaptchaImage
{

 /**
  * !!! Override this function to point to the new helper.
  * Get helper name used to render captcha
  *
  * @return string
  */
 public function getHelperName()
 {
     return 'viewhelpercaptcha';
 }
}
```

The only thing left to do is use it in a form.

```
//Create our custom captcha class
$captchaImage = new CustomCaptcha(  array(
   'font' => $dirdata . '/fonts/arial.ttf',
   'width' => 200,
   'height' => 100,
   'wordLen' => 5,
   'dotNoiseLevel' => 50,
   'lineNoiseLevel' => 3)
 );
 $captchaImage->setImgDir($dirdata.'/captcha');
 $captchaImage->setImgUrl($urlcaptcha);
//Create a form element captcha adding our custom captcha
// created above.
$this->add(array(
'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Captcha',
'name' => 'captcha',
'options' => array(
'label' => 'Please verify you are human',
'captcha' => $captchaImage,
),
```

));

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

To render an *Zend\Captcha\Image* directly in the view you can use this simple code.

```
<?php
  $captchaName = 'captcha'; // This is the name as given in form declaration

  $captcha = $form->get($captchaName)->getCaptcha();
  $captcha->generate();
?>
<div>
  <?= $this->formLabel($form->get($captchaName)) ?>
  <img width="<?= $captcha->getWidth() ?>" height="<?= $captcha->getHeight() ?>" src="<?= $captcha->getImgUrl() . $captcha->getId() . $captcha->getSuffix(); ?>" alt="<?= $captcha->getImgAlt() ?>">
  <input type="text" name="<?= $captchaName ?>[input]">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?= $captcha->getId() ?>" name="<?= $captchaName ?>[id]">
</div>
```

Comment: this helped me a lot to customize the element in the template as I wanted. thank you